# Clear loaded ASP scripts

Tags: sharepoint, internet-explorer-8, fluid-layout

I am working in Sharepoint the first time.  I have installed Fluid 960.  This works beautifully in Chrome and FF but IE8 (a company standard that I must maintain) drops off the grid_5 when it is the third row in a grid_4, grid_7, grid_5.  I tried doing 4-6-6 and the 6 dropped off.  I tried the "alpha" and "omega" margin overrides.

Has anyone else run into this problem?

Comment: Cancel...whoever used this put in a comment and I finally found that they didn't close the comment.  It wiped out some ASP control...